# Keras model prediction gives opposite results

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, prediction

I trained a model called `model_2` in Keras and made predictions using `model.predict` but I notice as I rerun the code the results are completely different. For example, first time `column 0` has all probability values close to 1, but next time it has probability values all close to 0. Has it to do with the memory or the `stateful` parameter which I have seen mentioned in other posts?

```
X = df.iloc[:,1:10161]
X = X.to_numpy()                      
X = X.reshape([X.shape[0], X.shape[1],1]) 
X_train_1 = X[:,0:10080,:]
X_train_2 = X[:,10080:10160,:].reshape(17,80)

inputs_1 = keras.Input(shape=(10080, 1))
layer1 = Conv1D(64, 14)(inputs_1)
layer2 = layers.MaxPool1D(5)(layer1)
layer3 = Conv1D(64, 14)(layer2)       
layer4 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(layer3)
layer5 = layers.Dropout(0.2)(layer4)

inputs_2 = keras.Input(shape=(80,))
layer6 = layers.concatenate([layer5, inputs_2])
layer7 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(layer6)
layer8 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(layer7)
layer9 = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(layer8)

model_2 = keras.models.Model(inputs = [inputs_1, inputs_2], outputs = [layer9])

adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.0001)
model_2.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['acc'])

prediction = pd.DataFrame(model_2.predict([X_train_1,X_train_2]),index = df.iloc[:,0])  
pred = np.argmax(model_2.predict([X_train_1,X_train_2]), axis=1) 
display(prediction, pred)
```

Examples of the contradictory results:

trial 1:

```
    0               1
id      
11  1.131853e-07    1.000000
22  1.003963e-06    0.999999
33  1.226156e-07    1.000000
44  9.985497e-08    1.000000
55  1.234705e-07    1.000000
66  1.189311e-07    1.000000
77  6.631822e-08    1.000000
88  9.586067e-08    1.000000
99  9.494666e-08    1.000000
```

trial 2:

```
    0           1
id      
11  0.183640    0.816360
22  0.487814    0.512187
33  0.151600    0.848400
44  0.135977    0.864023
55  0.120982    0.879018
66  0.171371    0.828629
77  0.199774    0.800226
88  0.133711    0.866289
99  0.125785    0.874215
```

trial 3:

```
    0           1
id      
11  0.900128    0.099872
22  0.573520    0.426480
33  0.948409    0.051591
44  0.955184    0.044816
55  0.959075    0.040925
66  0.945758    0.054242
77  0.956582    0.043418
88  0.954180    0.045820
99  0.964601    0.035399
```

trial 4:

```
    0   1
id      
11  1.0 4.697790e-08
22  1.0 2.018885e-07
33  1.0 2.911827e-08
44  1.0 2.904826e-08
55  1.0 1.368165e-08
66  1.0 2.742492e-08
77  1.0 1.461449e-08
88  1.0 2.302636e-08
99  1.0 2.099636e-08
```

---

Model was been trained with:

```
n_folds = 10
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_folds, shuffle=True)
skf = skf.split(X_train_1, Y_cat)

cv_score = []

for i, (train, test) in enumerate(skf):

    model_2 = my_model()

    history = model_2.fit([X_train_1[train], X_train_2[train]], Y[train], validation_data=([X_train_1[test], X_train_2[test]], Y[test]), epochs=120, batch_size=10) 
    
    result = model_2.evaluate([X_train_1[test], X_train_2[test]], Y[test])
    keras.backend.clear_session()
```

Comment: Are you training on exactly the same data each time? Even a change in input sequence could affect output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's completely normal, when you create a new model, its weights are initialized as random, so the prediction will change each time you run this code.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thanks for the answer, but this doesn't seem to make sense, I'd have imagined the results to be at least similar, rather than being completely opposite?

Comment: The softmax activation layer bounds the results, so even being the weight randomized, is more probable to obtain those opposite results. But as I said, this is expected behavior if the model is not trained.

Comment: Oh I have trained the model and it's called model_2

Comment: The model is not training in your code snippet posted.

Comment: The `model_2.fit(...)` statement is missing.

Comment: Please see question edit. I trained the model first. But I refined the layers again (in the first chunk of code), am I not supposed to redefine the layers and instead should just use model_2 for prediction?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230008/discussion-between-sebastian-borquez-gonzalez-and-nilsinelabore).

Answer (score 1):

After you train a model, you have store the weights of that model in a file. If you don't do this, you don't keep the trained models if you run your program (or any other) again.

You can store the model weights during training by using the ModelCheckpoint callback. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint

You can load the weights before inference (prediction) using model.load_weights(...)
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load

To clarify why your results are random. You keep initializing a new model with random weights and then directly try to predict the answer with the untrained model.

[EDIT]
The reason your untrained model keeps giving the opposite results, may be due to the inputs combined with the weight initialization. The weight initialization is random, but there is some "smarts" behind the initialization to prevent dead connections. Here you can find more details on all weight initializers: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

U need to fix the random generator seeds for both tensorflow and sklearn.
Try the following:

```
tf.random.set_seed(42)
```

and

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
```

This will allow you to replicate your results.